# how to replace value in a row of just few columns without merge in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1 which has almost 100k rows and another df2 with just around 10 rows. I need to replace the value in df1 with df2 for just the 30 rows on exact matching of two column values.

```
df1:
Daily_No     Date      Name      Type       Amount     
   A12    30/01/2020    Bob       R           400        
   A14    30/01/2020    Jacob     R           1000       
   B01    31/01/2020    John      D           20         

df2:
Old_Date       New_Date       Daily_No       Type       Amount     Balance
30/01/2020    05/02/2020         A12           R         10000         0
30/01/2020    06/02/2020        KO11           D          200         10
10/08/2020    06/02/2020        B01            D          5           0
```

I want to replace the df1 column `[Daily_No,  **Date**,  Name,  Type, Amount]` with values in row values of `[Daily_No, **New_Date**, '' , Type , Amount]` respectively, in other words copy New_Date and other details (except Balance and Old_Date: as balances is not in df1 already and Date in df1 to be replaced by New_Date) to Date and other columns on matching `left_on=['Date', 'Daily_No'], right_on=['Old_Date', 'Daily_No']`

As there is just 10 rows in df2, is there a faster way to copy the column values on matching the two columns?

Desired output

```
Daily_No     Date      Name   Type    Amount     
   A12    05/02/2020    Bob    R      10000 <---df2 row 1 match(replaced Date with New_Date, Type, Amount)
   A14    30/01/2020    Jacob  R      1000 <---df2 no matches
   B01    31/01/2020    John   D        20  <---df2 date didn't match
```

Comment: why can't you use merge?

Comment: @Datanovice I think it takes more time....atlast it is just 10 rows..merging will take time right ? Also will create double column with _x and _y suffixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `combine_first` as you don't want to merge.

```
df3 = df2.rename(columns={"Old_Date": "Date"}).set_index(["Date", "Daily_No"])[["Amount"]]\
    .combine_first(
    df1.set_index(['Date','Daily_No'])).dropna().reset_index()

print(df3)

         Date Daily_No   Amount   Name Type
0  30/01/2020      A12  10000.0    Bob    R
1  30/01/2020      A14   1000.0  Jacob    R
2  31/01/2020      B01     20.0   John    D
```

---

Another method would be to concat based on the mutual columns, ffill & drop_duplicates keeping only the later value.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,
       df2.rename(columns={'Old_Date': 'Date'})[['Date','Amount','Daily_No']]

      ],axis=0,sort=False)

df3.fillna(df3.groupby(['Daily_No','Date'],
            sort=False).ffill()).dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=['Daily_No','Date'],keep='last')

print(df3)


  Daily_No        Date   Name Type  Amount
1      A14  30/01/2020  Jacob    R    1000
2      B01  31/01/2020   John    D      20
0      A12  30/01/2020    Bob    R   10000
```

Comment: can we do it using iloc or something...this works but it is a bit long lines for this right? idk.. please comment

Comment: @Derik81 `iloc` will only work if indexes are aligned, you could create a surrogate key in both dataframes and use `.map`