# how to replace row value like a vlookup in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to df

```
df1 with almost 100k rows
Name1     Amount1    Type1       Balance1
A          10          R            2
B          10          D            0
B          5           R           10
C          5           R            0
```

I need to replace the row when the df2 has the match for both `Name and Type`
here is the df2 - has just 6 rows usually

```
Name2     Amount2    Type2       Balance2
B          5000        D            200
C          5           R            100
D          10          Q              0
```

I want to copy Amount2 to Amount1 & Balance2 to Balance1 when [Name1, Type1] == [Name2, Type2]
which is the better way to do this ?

Desired Output:
All 100k rows of df1 should remain in df1 itself. the unmatched rows in df2 should **NOT** be added as a row in df1 (it is to be ignored). New value of Amount2 and Balance2 should replace the Amount1 and Balance2.

```
Name1     Amount1    Type1       Balance1
A          10          R            2
B          5000        D           100     <---Both Amount and balance changed
B          5           R           10      <---Type1 != Type2 in this case
C          5           R            100    <---Balance changed
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61764611/9375102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the respective columns as indexes and use `update`:

```
# make sure df1 and df2 has the same column names
df2.columns=df1.columns

# set index
df1 = df1.set_index(['Name1','Type1'])

df1.update(df2.set_index(['Name1','Type1']))

# reset index
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Name1 Type1  Amount1  Balance1
0     A     R     10.0       2.0
1     B     D   5000.0     200.0
2     B     R      5.0      10.0
3     C     R      5.0     100.0
```